# Question about mongo db schema and performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-schema

I have 2 collections *all_files* and *trashed_files*. File item object in each of these collections is the same `{ name, type, metadata }`. Is it a good idea to create only one collection with one boolean property *isTrashed* in the file item object like `{ name, type, metadata, isTrashed }` and delete the *trashed_files* collection?

Currently to delete the file item, I have first delete item from *all_files* collection and add it to *trashed_files* collection. Although mongo operations are atomic, this requires two operations. With the new schema I will only have to update *isTrashed* property for the concerned file item. But my worry is that for a very large collection this will lead to slow performance when I want to find all trashed files from the *all_files* collection.

Which schema is better? I have read about single/multi table inheritance and denormalized nature of the mongodb.

Comment: You will benefit from removing the data duplication (saves disk space, memory and maintenance) - by having a single collection. What was the reason why there are two collections with same data - needs to be understood clearly.

Comment: @prasad_ Well idea behind for 2 separate models have to do with separation of concerns. If a single model is maintained then every time I make a request, I have to make sure to filter out trashed files. Example I am trying to find out liked files, and some of the liked files are trashed, if I don't filter out trashed files I may end up serving them instead. And later I might have other filters like synced, offline, etc

Comment: Then, you need to look at the CRUD queries you perform most often on the data - what queries are important, how much data you are handling are some of the main concerns.